# nginx> This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, https

I have configured HTTPS (on nginx) with the same configuration on `*.domain.com` of two servers in Ubuntu. One server is `api.domain.com` and the other is `staging-api.domain.com`. My server configuration is like this:

```
server {
                listen       443  ssl;
                server_name  api.domain.com;
                #root /usr/share/nginx/html;

                ssl on;
                ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
                ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
                ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
                ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
                ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/star.domain.com/8592215832301494.crt;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/star.domain.com/server.key;
                ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/star.domain.com/gd_bundle.pem;
       }
```

`api.domain.com` (nginx version 1.4.6) gets A rating in ssl test and everything is OK.
But `staging-api.domain.com` (nginx version 1.10.1) is B grade. The message is "This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B."

Is this a problem of my Nginx version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a problem of the nginx version but of its configuration. Both the server certificate and all the needed chain certificates must be contained in the file set by `ssl_certificate` and they must also be in the right order.

For more information see [SSL certificate chains](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains) in the nginx documentation.

Comment: I have only certifications like this: 
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1842 Mar 16  2015 8592215832301494.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4795 Mar 16  2015 gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1728 Oct 26 11:41 gd_bundle.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5681 Mar 16  2015 private.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1062 Mar 16  2015 server.csr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1679 Mar 16  2015 server.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1842 Mar 16  2015 domaincert.pem `
and cant find the solution.

Comment: @IftikharHossain: it's the contents of these file which matters not their size.

Comment: @IftikharHossain: the servers certificate first and then the issuer if this certificate etc. With most CA you get the needed information when you buy a certificate  so you might just check out there.

Comment: You can check the chain at https://whatsmychaincert.com/?staging-api.domain.com. This also has a "Generate Chain" button that create a file with your certificate + intermediate certificates that you can download and add to your web server config.

Answer (score 0):

The Nginx documentation talks of cert and key like so:

```
ssl_certificate     www.example.com.chained.crt;
ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;
```

But these names don't correspond to the current letsencrypt.org SSL files.

For those you want to specify these files:

```
ssl_certificate      /path/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /path/privkey.pem;
```

Then, when you test your SSL config with a site like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/  you'll win an overall rating of grade 'A'.   Which is reassuring. :)